# Post title font cut off under review queue

Tags: bug, design, review-page

Consider the following review when viewed through Google Chrome:

[image]

---

Here's the same review through Firefox:

[image]

---

Here's the same review through IE:

[image]

---

Both Chrome and IE cut parts of the descenders off the post titles. Please fix this.

<sub>Haven't tested on Safari or other browsers.</sub>

Comment: After installing some Helvetica variants, I can confirm that it can be your system too. Chrome and Firefox is showing different rendering of the regular text.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247571/237813